# When overriding can comparing object ever be null?

Tags: java

When overriding `equals` method for an object can `obj` below ever be `null`, if so what are the circumstances?

```
@Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
```

Comment: You mean that `obj` could be `null`?

Comment: it will be null if you pass it null as parameter,

Comment: @Andremoniy yes obj could be null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `equals()` should handle `null` and in that case it should return `false` as documented in [`Object.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

Of course if `x` **is** `null` `x.equals(null)` won't return `true` but it will throw `NullPointerException`. If you need to compare two possibly `null` references look at [`Objects.equals(Object, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)):

```
Objects.equals(x, x);
```

The above is always `true`, even if `x == null`.

Answer (score 5):

It's a public method. It can be null whenever a caller passes a null value into it. You have to handle that case appropriately.